# Flot. Time Series. One Tick Per Day

Tags: jquery, time, flot

I'm currently trying to create a flot graph where the x axis is a time series and has one tick per day. So for example if I was showing a graph for November I'd get a tick for each day in November.

My xaxis config looks like this :-

```
 xaxis: { min: Date.UTC(2010, 0, 0, 0, 0), max: Date.UTC(2010, 1, 0, 0, 0),
                        mode: "time",  
                        minTickSize: [1, "day"] 
                    }
```

I think at the moment flot is trying to auto scale the xaxis so I'm actually getting one tick every 3 days.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

change `minTickSize` to `tickSize`